# drupal_write_record() cuts off data

Tags: database

I have some pretty straightforward code that combines some string values together and then writes them to the db using drupal_write_record(), and it seems that the values are getting cut off for some reason when actually written to the database.

```
$keys_string = str_replace('|', '', $product->attribute_keys);
$values_string = str_replace('|', '', $product->attribute_values);

$keys = array_filter(explode('~', $keys_string));
$values = array_filter(explode('~', $values_string));

$description = '';
foreach ($keys as $key => $data) {
    $description .= $keys[$key] . ' : ' . $values[$key] . "\n";
}

$description .= "\n" . $product->group_text; 
....

// Write record to database.
$table = 'ridethis_combined';
$record = new stdClass();
$record->title = $title;
$record->description = $description;
$record->short_description = $product->group_text;
$record->upc = $product->upc;
$record->sku = $product->vendor_item_id;
$record->cost = $price;
$record->price = $price;
$record->bti_quantity = $product->available;
$record->hawley_quantity = NULL;
$record->weight = NULL;
$record->manufacturer = $product->manufacturer_name;
$record->image = $image_url;
$record->meta_description = $product->group_text;
$record->meta_keyword = $product->group_text;
$record->meta_title = $title;

drupal_write_record($table, $record);
```

When stepping through the code in a debugger, I can see that prior to drupal_write_record, the full concatenated value is is stored in $record->description.  However, when I view the data in MySQL, only the concatenated values from $product->attribute_keys and $product->attribute_values is there; it's as if the $product->group_text data was never there.  The size of the db field is not an issue, since it has plenty of space for the content I'm writing to it.

Do you have any thought on what could be cutting this text off?

Comment: Does the description column in MySQL is big enough to store the datas ? Does this table has a schema which would have an incorrect size for this column ?

Comment: As I stated above, the size of the db field is not an issue, since it has plenty of space for the content I'm writing to it.

Comment: Can you post the CREATE syntax for your table?

Comment: There may be an issue with your use of \n in the string. Try using \\n or removing it entirely.

Comment: @cam8001 `drupal_write_record()` is present in Drupal 6 and forward; you implement `hook_schema()` to define the database tables used by a module.

Comment: @wonder95 Can you report the code you used to implement `hook_schema()`? I can only think of a reason why this happens, but I need to see how you define the database table in `hook_schema()` to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The function `drupal_write_record()` uses the database schema defined from the module. Check your `hook_schema()`, and see if it has the right length.

Post your `hook_schema()` implementation too, if this doesn't help.